# Compare two CSV files an update the second one

Tags: pandas, csv

I have to csv-files: allitems and allitemsnew.

I am trying to compare the two  files. If i have new rows in "allitems" I want to add this rows to the second file like an update.

This is my code but I don't know if I am on the right way:

```
# Read the file with latest update
dftemp = pd.read_csv('allitemsnew.csv', delimiter=',', header=None,engine='python', usecols=range(0, 7), error_bad_lines=False)

# Check if there is any change but only first column.
# Combine the two datas and append new data from originalfile
dfnew = dftemp.merge(df, how='outer')

# Delete dublicates because if I execute my programm without changes I get each time more and more duplicates
dfnew.drop_duplicates(subset=[0], inplace=True, keep=False)

# Intersection of both files because normally I append new rows from original file to the allitemsnew-file. 
# But if I delete rows from original file there are not also removed in the second file. Therefore intersection
dfwrite=df.merge(dfnew, how='inner')

dfwrite.to_csv("allitemsnew.csv", index=False, header=None)
```

My solution works but I don't know if this is the best way.

1. I want to compare to csv files
2. I want to update the second file with new new or deleted rows from first file
   Comparision only with first column because a function like "df.update()" overwrite all rows
3. I want to insert a new column at first only one time with status-rows. But it inserts only at last. I tried reindex-Function but it didn't work

Comment: Can you share example of input and desired output?

Comment: There really isn't a better way than merge. You could use `join`, but really this is the best way.